# How to know which register(s) is read from as it executed?

Tags: instructions

I have a question about these kinds of quizzes. What is the theory behind this?

Given the following instruction, which register(s) is read from as it is executed? (Select all that apply)
and $sp, $gp, $s4

A. $gp(answer)
B. $s4(answer)
C. $sp
D. None of these.

lb $sp, 7472($v1)

A. $v1(answer)
B. Program Counter
C. $sp
D. None of these.

Comment: No theory, just syntax.  Look up the instruction description in the instruction set reference for this architecture, and it will tell you what the instruction does, and which of its operands are read or written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following [manual](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html) is pretty good for MIPS assembly language.  It relates the instruction assembly form to a register transfer notation that describes what the processor does with that assembly instruction, for example, the first instruction is `sll $rd, $rt, shamt`, which does for its operation: `R[$rd] ← R[$rt] << shamt`.

A register is a target if the execution of the instruction assigns the register a value (which most likely changes the value held by the register, but doesn't have to; the old value held by the register is lost).  When there is a target, the register transfer notation will show how the register is updated, i.e. how the new value is computed.

You can determine which registers are sources vs. targets by looking at where they are in relation to the `←` that represents assignment.  When on the left as in `R[$rd] ←`, that is the target of an assignment, hence register `$rd` is a target, whereas when they appear on the right of assignment, that is a source register, as in `← R[$rt] << shamt`.

(As you may know, the `$` is commonly used to prefix register names with the MIPS assemblers / assembly languages.)

The [MIPS green sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) is also pretty good but is oriented toward machine code rather than assembly language, so you have to know the order of the machine code operands vs. the assembly form of the same instruction (which you can see from the first link).  In MIPS assembly language the target register, when present, is always the first operand, despite that in machine code the target register (when present) is always the last register field.

In the green sheet, that same MIPS instruction has the following definition:

| Description | Mnemonic | Format | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shift Left Logical | sll | R | R[rd] = R[rt] << shamt |

Not all instructions have target registers, for example, the load instructions have a target register, but the store instructions do not — the true target of store instructions is some memory location, so there is no target *register*.

Every instruction also informs the processor what instruction to run next.  Most instructions tell the processor to advance the program counter by 4 (the size in bytes of one MIPS instruction), which has the effect of saying that the next instruction is the one immediately following in memory from the currently executing instruction; this achieves the normal sequential execution of one instruction after the other.  (This behavior is so fundamental that most coursework and instruction manuals assume and gloss this aspect of instruction execution, noting for example, only when the PC is updated in manner other than sequential.)

Branch instructions interact with the program counter either in the normal way (to advance by 4 for sequential execution) or to move it backwards (e.g. to accomplish a loop) or forwards (e.g. to exit a loop or skip a then or else part).  Branch instructions also do not have a target register — their effect is solely with the program counter.